# How do I combine multiple selects and link tables in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I don't think this question has been asked elsewhere but please feel free to let me know if you think otherwise.

I have two tables like so:

```
Table A (Transactions)
id ¦ player_id ¦ t_out ¦ team_id

Table B (Players)
id ¦ club_id
```

What I need to do is count the number of entries in Table A that have a specific table B.club_id while Table A.t_out is null and Table A.team_id is a specific value.

Things to note:
Table A.player_id refers to Table B.id

I've had a look through the MySql help docs but can't seem to piece it together.

Comment: Have you looked at JOIN statements? - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Yes but I can't figure how to do it right

Comment: @dotnetom, by editing this page, and using the original revision, you've essentially [rejected my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8352557). I fixed this already, (Much clearer than your edit), and I'm unable to make any future changes to this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `transactions` t
LEFT JOIN `players` p ON p.`player_id` = t.`id`
WHERE p.club_id = X AND t.t_out IS NULL AND t.team_id = X
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN y... WHERE y is the same as INNER JOIN y

Comment: This worked although I had wrongly specified t_out as NULL where it should have been 0